# Update Database - php

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to update a database records when a user hits a submit button with the ID of 'Save' but it's not working,  here's what I have for the MYSQL update query:

```
    if ($_POST['SaveCall'] ) {


// set database server access variables:
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "TILRenewals";

// open connection
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!");


// select database
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to Choose database!");







$SPKCustNo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SPKSelect']);

$FName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FName']);
$SName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SName']);
$PostCode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PostCode']);
$Product = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Product']);
$PaymentMethod = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PaaymentMethod']);
$RenewalDate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Renewa;Date']);
$HomeTel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['HomeTel']);
$WorkTel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['WorkTel']);
$Priority = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PriorityCheckBox']);
$Call1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Call1']);
$Call1Notes = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Call1Notes']);

$Call2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Call2']);
$Call2Notes = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Call2Notes']);

$Call3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Call3']);
$Call3Notes = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Call3Notes']);

$Call4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Call4']);
$Call4Notes = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Call4Notes']);

$Call5 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Call5']);
$Call5Notes = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Call5Notes']);

$Outcome = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Outcome']);


$sql="UPDATE Data
SET ForeName = '$FName', Surname='$SName', PostCode='$PostCode', Product='$Product', PaymentMethod='$PaymentMethod',RenewalDate='$RenewalDate',HomeTel='$HomeTel,WorkTel='$WorkTel',Priority='$Priority',Call1='$Call1',Call1Notes='$Call1Notes',Call2='$Call2',Call2Notes='$Call2Notes',Call3='$Call3',Call3Notes='$Call3Notes',Call4='$Call4',Call4Notes='$Call4Notes',Call5='$Call5',Call5Notes='$Call5Notes',Outcome='$Outcome'
WHERE SPKCustNo='$SPKCustNo' ";


mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); ;

}


?>
```

Can anyone help?  Thankyou!

* Have edited the above to include the connection to the DB and sending the query, Now I get: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '01268510268',Priority='1',Call1='03/10/12',Call1Notes='Test Call 1 Notes',Call2=' at line 2

Comment: You are never sending the query to the server?

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Comment: It's good that you're properly escaping your query parameters, but this would be *significantly* easier if you were using PDO or `mysqli`. The `mysql_query` interface is deprecated and should not be used in new applications.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working". State what you expect to get and what you get instead.

Comment: This calls for basic debugging first. Where does it fail? What does the final query look like?

Comment: I'm not sure where it fails, if I remove or die(mysql_error()); from mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); I get nothing, no error messages or anything in Page Source, it just doesn't write to the DB.

Comment: @Pekka please see above edits for the error message I'm getting now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, assuming that is all the code, you have. I do not see where you have connected to the database, assuming you did connect to the database. You did not execute the query.

Once you have the sql query in $sql, perform this operation. 
`mysql_query($sql);`

**Edit**

You did not close the quotes near after `$Hometel`.

Comment: Edited the above main quesiton to show everything I have now.

Comment: You did not close the quotes near after $Hometel

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

it will give you errors

if u cant fix it, post it here. you will get help.

Comment: Now it just says 'Query is Empty' in the page source as soon as the page is loaded. Have edited the main question to reflect what I've got now.

Comment: Please see the above edits to see what I'm getting now :)

Comment: Don't use mysql_* commands... They are deprecated. Use wither mysqli_* or PDO